# trying to change the text of edittext object inside a fragment

Tags: android

I have a fragment that containd a EditText.  Usally I get the address of the EditTExt by calling findViewById  to get the object, then I call setText to chnage the text.

When I call findViewById, I get a error saying
"cannot resolve methed  findViewById.  I'm assuming the Fragment class does not support this methed.

HHow can I chnage the text?
My code

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    EditText editText;
    editText = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.textViewVol));
    editText.setText("% Volumne");

}
```

Comment: There is couple errors in your code. Instead `onActivityCreated` override 
`onViewCreated` than inside you can write `editText = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewVol)`. But don't try to `cast` an `EditText` to `TextView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

You have to pass the instance of view of the fragment that you instantiate in your onCreateView method:

```
private View mView;
private EditText editText;

 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (mView != null) {
                ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) mView.getParent();
                if (group != null) {
                    group.removeView(mView);
                }
            } else {
                //Inflate layout for this fragment
                mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.frgament_layout, container, false);

                edittext = (TextView)(mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewVol));
                editText.setText("% Volumne");
            return mView;
        }
```